# kivymd setup and running issues around Navigation

Tags: kivymd

I am having issues creating and kicking off a simple KivyMd app. I basically follow the setup steps provided by in this tutorial video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycoKlFV3-iU

However I am running into this issue.
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\card\card.kv'

I can see the kv file in the directory
[image]

[image]

I can clearly see the card.kv file. Here is the code in the main.py and .kv file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
```

from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

class MainApp(MDApp):
theme_cls = ThemeManager()

MainApp().run()

any suggestion on setup or what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated